# Keep cost low at SOAP service version update

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, soap-client

Some of my collegues and I were discussing today what the correct term is when you switch from one Version of an interface to another.

We have another company who has an Soap webservice. They switched/updated their service from one version to another, but the changes are so drastic that you have to reimplement 60% of the code that accesses the SOAP webservice.

[image]

1. is there a design pattern which helps you keep the work at a minimum level if such an update happens ?
2. if you know how to do it then you probably know what the correct term is for that kind of implementation, is it reengeneering or refactoring or what ?

Comment: The Protobuffers sales spiel sort of addresses this, albeit from a different angle. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: @tripleee I haven't heard of Protobuffers until yet. Very interesting. But it seems this solves the problem from the server side, or at least without access to its sourcecode I am not able to solve it with Protobuffers, am I correct ?

Comment: Take a look at the Adapter pattern for the current predicament.  For future proofing, need to make sure there is a clear boundary layer between your code and the third party code and that its needs don't leak beyond that interface layer. The design principal should be that only that layer needs to change if the API does (harder than it sounds). Again the adapter pattern can help here